# find texmf directory

Tags: fonts, tex-core

The page https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/carlito says to install the font, I have to

> Unzip the archive at the root of an appropriate texmf tree,
> likely a personal or local tree.

How can I find the texmf directory, which tex uses?

Comment: there should be no need to install it manually. The package is in texlive and miktex, so use their package manager.

Comment: Yeah, I got it installed with `zypper install texlive-carlito`.